# Laravel 5 event not working

Tags: events, laravel-5

Sr, I am try to using laravel 5 with this example below, but it not working.

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DidSomething extends Event {
    use SerializesModels;
    public function __construct() {
     return;
    }
}
```

and handles

namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\DidSomething;

```
class DoSomething {
    public function __construct() {
    }
    public function handle(DidSomething $event) {
      dd($event);
    } 
 }
```

and my EventServiceProvider.php

```
 namespace App\Providers;

 use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as    ServiceProvider;

 class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   /**
   * The event handler mappings for the application.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $listen = [
        App\Events\DidSomething::class=>[
                App\Handlers\Events\DoSomething::class
        ]
   ];

/**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    //
}
```

}

In my controller, i used \Event::fire(new DidSomething());

And I had tried with command line

```
php artisan event:generate
php artisan optimize
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. generate an event

   art make:event LogMe
2. generate an event handler for that event

   art handler:event LogMe --event="LogMe"
3. make sure to register the event and it’s hander in the event service `provider (app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php)`

//

```
protected $listen = [
   'event.name' => [
      'EventListener',
   ],

       \Xxx\Events\LogMe::class => [
             \Xxx\Handlers\Events\LogMe::class,
       ],

];
```

4. fire an event
   `Event::fire(New LogMe());`        -or- you can use the event helper          `event(New LogMe());`

> alternatively you can generate an event by simply registering the event in the service provider then running this command
>   `art event:generate`                  << this will automatically add the two classes for you

5. you can listen to an event without creating an event handler or registering a lister in the listeners array.

*go to the event service prover and inside the boot function write your event and its action (NOT RECOMMENDED)*

```
Event::listen('XXX\Events\DoSomethingElse', function($event)
{
     dd('handle me :)');
});
```

6. you can queue an event or even subscribe to multiple events from within the class itself